# Best way to get prior value from today

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, logic, concept

I am working on requirement and need to check about my logic that I have implemented. Please help.

I want to get the 1 month,3 month and 6 month return % of stock price from current date.
I have a table which have date and price array field as shown.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a65d0e7bfd103df081a75a8"),
"aId" : 93,
"values" : [ 
    {
        "date" : "2018-02-06",
        "Price" : 27.9057
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "2018-02-05",
        "Price" : 28.0406
    }
  ]
}
```

## My logic

1. Iterate through the date,price array and pass the date to a function which will calculate days difference.

   ```
   function differenceFromTodayInDays(FromDate) {
       var currentDate = new Date();
       var previousDate = new Date(FromDate);
       var difference = Math.floor(currentDate.getTime() - previousDate.getTime());
       var secs = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
       var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
       var hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
       var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
       return days;
   }
   ```
2. Push the days into different arrays if days = 30,31 or 60,61 or 91,90,92,93

   ```
   if (differenceInDays == 30 || differenceInDays == 31) {
       $scope.days30.push(index);
   ```

so overall till now

```
 $scope.timeDiffInDays = function(index, otherDate) {
    $scope.days30 = [];
    var differenceInDays = differenceFromTodayInDays(otherDate);
    if (differenceInDays == 30 || differenceInDays == 31) {
        $scope.days30.push(index);
     }
}
```

Here I have index and can take the price value of that index and calculate return % from current value.

## My Concerns are

1. Values in array are increasing daily and it will slow down process.
2. Date Difference of 30/31/60/61/90/91 is not available sometimes as some days are holidays and those values are not there in array.so it is hard to get return %.

I am looking for some efficient logic for this.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly why you are including date part in your code? Get month and year only and write a code like (endyear-startyear)*12+(endmonth-startmonth)- (enddate>=startdate?0:1).

I don't have laptop support now(writing from phone). I think getMonth() and getFullYear() will help you to do this